# Get points on arc with center, start and end points given

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I'm trying to find a simple solution for getting a set of points on arc.
My program runs with c#, wpf and telerik.

In my program I have a map, with camera's FOV (field of view) on it.
Till now I had triangular fov , but client wants it with an arc.
I have a center point (camera's origin) with two points representing left and right FOV boundaries.
The points are represented as coordinates.

[A draw of what I wish to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiDx2.jpg)

My goal is to gather a set of points on top of the arc which connects the FOV limits (left and right points), which then I'll send to telerik to draw.

some remarks:

1. I know telerik can draw arc, but it has weird [binding problems](http://www.telerik.com/forums/custom-mapshape)
2. I saw some answers (not really helpful) saying to calculate the circle equation and continue from there. I wish to avoid it if possible.

Does c# and Math class has some tools which can help? 
I tried calculating it by myself, but it got too complicated for me to handle.

Thanks,
Naor.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Path` control with an appropriate `PathGeometry` that contains an `ArcSegment`.

In the example below, `(100,100)` is the center point and `(50,50)` and `(150,50)` are the start and end points of the arc. Note that the arc is a segment of an ellipse, where the `Size` property of the ArcSegment specifies the ellipse radii. Here it is a circle of radius `50*sqrt(2)`.

```
<Path Stroke="Black">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="100,100" IsClosed="True">
                <LineSegment Point="50,50"/>
                <ArcSegment Point="150,50" Size="70.7,70.7" SweepDirection="Clockwise"/>
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Or shorter:

```
<Path Stroke="Black" Data="M100,100 L50,50 A70.7,70.7 0 0 1 150,50Z" />
```

---

Assuming that your view model has four properties that describe the arc figure like

```
public Point Center { get; private set; } = new Point(100, 100);
public Point Start { get; private set; } = new Point(50, 50);
public Point End { get; private set; } = new Point(150, 50);
public Size Size { get; private set; } = new Size(70.7, 70.7);
```

you could write the XAML with Bindings like this:

```
<PathFigure StartPoint="{Binding Center}" IsClosed="True">
    <LineSegment Point="{Binding Start}"/>
    <ArcSegment Point="{Binding End}" Size="{Binding Size}" SweepDirection="Clockwise"/>
</PathFigure>
```

---

You can of course also create such a geometry in code behind.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I mentioned before, it has weird binding problems.  I need to bind point value to it, and it's not possible (link in first remark). Code behind option is also not good because of the project layout. I wish I could avoid this math calculation, but it's the easiest result for my situation.

Comment: I'm not talking about any Telerik component. ArcSegment is part of WPF, and all properties in the above XAML are of course bindable. See the edited answer.

Comment: Do you know if it supposed to work on top of telerik layer?  This is a large scale project, and I can't really change the implementation so far. Moreover, I tried to use it via DataTemplate. Does it make any difference? should I use other Object in order for it to work? Thank you

Comment: It should work well together, e.g. in a DataTemplate of a Telerik control.